# Can I prevent the Facebook RSS feed from causing a JavaScript syntax error?

Tags: javascript, facebook, rss

I'm including my Facebook RSS feed on a couple pages within my site, but it's triggering a JavaScript error when viewed within IE7 and IE8.

Our home page is one of the pages throwing this error, and the URL for that page is http://www.npca.org/

The RSS feed that is being displayed is located at https://www.facebook.com/feeds/page.php?format=rss20&id=8473889271

And I believe this is the part of the feed that is causing the syntax error:

```
onmousedown="UntrustedLink.bootstrap($(this), "jAQFkd_CS", event, bagof({}));"
```

Does anybody have any suggestions?

Comment: hi,did you ever get around this? I'm having the same issue.

Answer (score 1):

The error is improper use of encapsulated quotation marks. Change the code to this:

```
onmousedown="UntrustedLink.bootstrap($(this), 'jAQFkd_CS', event, bagof({}));"
```

Notice how my code snippet is interpreted and displayed with different coloration for jAQFkd_CS even on this page.